# Crystal report selection - Selecting a range of IDs not printing all reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Thanks for stopping by to help me out!

I am trying to make a crystal report print multiple reports given a range of IDs (From user input: IDfrom and IDto). One of the issues may be that the IDs are stored as text on the database but I have tried taking care of this by entering the following in the formula editor for the Record selection:

```
TONUMBER({table.ID}) in [TONUMBER({?IDfrom}) to TONUMBER({?IDto})]
```

This works somewhat, but it only prints a subset of the reports that are to be printed. If I have a range of one number (i.e. IDfrom=IDto) Then all the reports for the ID are printed.

To give a bit of context, each ID pertains to an order and each order has various line items, hence I would like to print a report for each line item.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It might help if you could share the values you are using for {?IDfrom} and {?IDto}, along with any values of {table.ID} that are printing on the report that are out of scope for the range of values.  I don't see anything wrong with your Record Select formula, so I suspect the issue may be in the data, its data type, or the casting to a numeric type.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the issue was that the records hold some old IDs which contained letters as well as numbers, so the casting wasn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that some old ID records were not only made up of numbers but had letters as well. This I think was stuffing up the selection.